# Electroweak symmetry breaking and mass generation

Tags: particle-physics, mass

Can someone please describe how the mass of the fermions is generated by the Higgs relative to electroweak symmetry breaking? Or other way around: Why does a breaking of the electroweak symmetry generate a  fermion mass?

Hence, what's the difference to chiral symmetry breaking which causes, e.g., the pion masses?

I found it on [Particle mass acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#Particle_mass_acquisition)
and there is maybe an another question related to: [Massive Gauge Bosons without Higgs fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194813/massive-gauge-bosons-without-higgs-fields)

That are probably very plain questions aiming at a general understanding/access. I'm trying to separate the involving terms and mechanisms from each other..

Comment: Hi Ben. There are lots of [related questions already on the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=higgs+mass+mechanism+is%3Aquestion). Can you be a bit more specific? What aspects of the Higgs mechanism do the existing questions not already cover?

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks, as far as I understand, on the linked question, there is no mention about the chiral symmetry breaking which also generates mass. Or is that higgs mechanism, too?

Comment: I think the answer by Lubos here  covers your chirality confusion . https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45450/what-is-the-relation-between-the-higgs-field-and-chirality .  " The origin of the chiral symmetry breaking is the strong nuclear force, mediated by gluons and described by QCD, rather than the weak nuclear force, mediated by the W-bosons and Z-bosons and made possible by the Higgs field. " So it is the mass of the composite hadronic fermions that is affected by the chiral symmetry.